# Referencing of interface makes my app crash (android/libgdx)

Tags: android, interface, android-activity, libgdx

I've made an interface to be able to call methods in my activity class from another class, but the moment I make a refernce the app crashes.

Error :
03-07 22:29:08.920: E/InputDispatcher(16000): channel '4194a380 com.mycompany.game1/com.mycompany.game1.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8

I am what you'd call a java noob, so I have no idea what's happening :)

Here's my 3 files simplified :

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements ActivityInterface {

    public void testMe(){       
        Gdx.app.log("hahah", "hahahahaa");
     }
}

public class TitleScreen extends Screen {

    public TitleScreen (){
        MainActivity m = new MainActivity(); // it crashes here
    }

}

public interface ActivityInterface {

    public void testMe();

}
```

Comment: Never ever create an `Activity` like you're trying to do. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by calling methods on another `Activity`? There can be only one `Activity` "alive" at any given time (basically), so you won't get anything out of creating a new instance of another `Activity` and try to call methods on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Activities don't like it to get instanciated that way:

```
MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
```

Moreover in libgdx you should not try to launch an android activity from a Screen class, because Screen is part of your game logic and you want your game logic to be **platform-independent** ==> you should have a separate android project to launch your main libgdx game

==> **conclusion**: just forget about instantiating your whole activity to your game screen. What should the desktop-version / browser version do with an android activity class anyway?

Comment: How do I call methods in the activity class then?
The thing is that I've added some pop-up code from appnext.com (an ad) and their code seems to only work within the activity class, but I want their pop-up to show up when I switch from one screen to the next.

Comment: I see. The thing is that the android ad banners will only work on android devices. So you will have to adjust your android project. You can do something similar like explained in this tutorial, it is with different ad provider, but should be somewhat similar: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

Comment: donfuxx, thanks - I got it to work by following your link.. well, I swithced to admob and got that to work, which is fine :) Now let me try and figure out how to make your reply and answer here.

Comment: @MichaelOlesen Excellent! :-)